Deserialize no tiene en cuenta atributo StringLength
en Net 8 tengo una clase Agente, cuyas propiedades tienen un atributo StringLength.
En un procedimiento recibo un JSON el cual en la propiedad Tipo llega con un valor ABCDEFG de longitud 7, que es mayor a la permitida según el atributo StringLength(4).
Al deserializar NO da ningún error; evidentemente ignora los atributos de las propiedades.
A mi entender debería haber dado un error similar a lo siguiente:
"One or more validation errors occurred."
The field Tipo must be a string with a maximum length of 4.
PREGUNTA: Que debo hacer para que valide los atributos de las propiedades y de el error correspondiente?
    public class Agente
    {
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
    
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
    
        public decimal Sueldo { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    Agente agente = new Agente();
    
    agente = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Agente>("                        {\"Codigo\":\"tst101\",\"Tipo\":\"ABCDEFG\",\"Sueldo\":123.45}", new JsonSerializerOptions());


Favor agregar la etiqueta C# a tu pregunta

Listo Yussef; muy agradecido por la pronta respiuesta y me aclaró mucho el tema. saludos!!

Son dos procesos distintos y separados:

(1) La deserialización
(2) La validación

Los DataAnnotations no impiden setear los valores de una propiedad, solo sirven para validar el modelo en un proceso posterior, por tanto al desearilzar  no dará nunca un problema
Para la validación en ASP, es simple basta con usar ModelState
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{ 
    foreach (var item in ModelState)
    {
        
    }
}

Para otros casos siempre puedes gatillar la validación
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Agente agente = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Agente>("{\"Codigo\":\"tst101\",\"Tipo\":\"ABCDEFG\",\"Sueldo\":123.45}", new JsonSerializerOptions());
        var validator = new ValidationContext(agente);
        var errorResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    
        if(!Validator.TryValidateObject(agente, validator, errorResults, true))  // ¿ es valido ?
        {
            foreach (var validationResult in errorResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }

        }
    }
}
public class Agente
{
    [StringLength(8)]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4)]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    public decimal Sueldo { get; set; }
}




yo aclararia, que los DataAnnotation solo son para ASP y sus modelos, por lo tanto, usarlos para validar otra cosa estaria bien, pero no es el objetivo. Las reglas de negocios, las debe validar el negocio.. en este caso el JSON se debe parsear y luego validar por reglas, no por anotaciones....

Yusser y gbianchi, muy agradecido por la respuesta; me quedó en claro las recomendaciones y ejemplos sobre el tema; gracias!!!
